# How to disable the unskippable intro videos in Borderlands 2 VR?

Tags: borderlands-2-vr

Borderlands 2  VR has an infamous problem where you can't skip the intro movies when you create a new character at the first start of the new game, and you have to wait for about 7 minutes until your next UI interaction is available. How to disable these intro cutscene movies completely?

Answer (score 2):

Locate the `WillowGame\Movies` folder in your Borderlands 2 VR installation directory and sort by file size. The biggest files here are our offenders:

- MegaIntro.bik - 441 MB
- Attract.bik - 227 MB

Simply rename them to something other than their original file names, like `_MegaIntro.bik`, and the game will skip them with no problems. There is no need to copy the smallest `.bik` file and rename it to match these names, as some other guides suggest, because there will be no problem anyway, and you don't want to see Angel's face unnecessarily.

And to speed up the game startup you can also disable these 3 game logo clips:

- NVidia.bik
- 2K_logo.bik
- Gearbox_logo.bik

By the way, this also works for regular Borderlands 2, and should also work for all other games in the series, since they all use the same engine.